# Android - I have an app with a BroadcastReceiver for reminders that pop-up in the notif. area. How to add a service?

Tags: android

In my app the user can set reminders.
The reminders pop-up at the desired time in the notification area even if the app has been closed/destroyed.
I am using a broadcast receiver at the moment.

How Do I add a service, so this works even at phone restart?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void addAlarmsToPushNotificationService(Context context, ArrayList<Alarm> alarms) {

    for (Alarm alarm : alarms) {
        Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmCalendar.setTimeInMillis(alarm.getTimeInMiliseconds());

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PushNotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationTitle", alarm.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("notificationText", alarm.getDescription());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), intent, 0); // The second arg is unique id

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); // Service.ALARM_SERVICE
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

} // End of addAlarmsToPushNotificationService
```

This is my receiver class

```
public class PushNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String notificationTitle = intent.getExtras().getString("notificationTitle");
        String notificationText = intent.getExtras().getString("notificationText");


        String soundResource = "android.resource://com.asdqwe.asd/raw/asd_tone";
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(soundResource);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentTitle(notificationTitle)//
                .setContentText(notificationText)//
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_application)//
                .setSound(soundUri)//
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_application));//

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(543, mBuilder.build());


    }

} // End of Class
```

And an excerpt from the Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.PushNotificationReceiver" />

    <service
        android:name=".services.PushNotificationService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

You can see I've prepared an empty class for the service, but I dont know what to do next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a BroadcastReceiver that receives a message  when the boot is completed:

```
     public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, your_service.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
}
```

In Your manifest You have to set permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And register the receiver:

```
    <receiver android:name="BroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: what is the relation between this receiver and the other receiver? what is the relation between my service and my receiver and what should my service include?

Comment: Your Receiver receives the message from the AlarmManager, but when You want to start something when the phone is rebooted, You have to set a receiver like I showed above. If You turn off Your phone, all AlarmManager setted intents get killed. Could You show the code from your PushNotificationService ?

Comment: I have no code in my pushnotificationservice class, because I dont know what to put in there :(

Comment: You don´t really need Your service here. You have to start addAlarmsToPushNotificationService() inside the BootCompleted receiver.

Comment: this sounds good, the only question left is, should I also call removeAlarmsFromPushNotificationService (another method that I use to clear the alarms) before adding them again to avoid duplicating the alarms, or are they cleared automatically at reboot?

Comment: by turning phone off, all alarms will be deleted automatically from the android system. There is no duplicate...